# regex - how to specify the expressions to exclude

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to replace two characters `{`, `}` with `{\n`, `\n}`.
But they must be not surrounded in `''` or `""`.

I tried this code to achieve that

```
text = 'hello(){imagine{myString("HELLO, {WORLD}!")}}'
replaced = re.sub(r'{', "{\n", text)
Ellipsis...
```

Naturally, This code replaces curly brackets that are surrounded in quote marks.

What are the negative statements like `!` or `not` that can be used in regular expressions?

And the following is what I wanted.

```
hello(){
imagine{
puts("{HELLO}")
}
}
```

In a nutshell - what I want to do is

1. Search `{` and `}`.
2. If that is not enclosed in `''` or `""`
3. replace `{` or `}` to `{\n` or `\n}`

In the opposite case, I can solve it with `(?P<a>\".*){(?P<b>.*?\")`.
But I have no clue how I can solve it in my case.

Comment: What kind of string literals do you have to support (to avoid matching braces in)? What kind of entities they may hold?

Comment: I just want to support quote marks. Probably that's all.

Comment: And if you want to write a `"` in a string? Will it be ``"text\"text"`` or ``"text""text"``?

Comment: I want to use the first one. thank you for your favor.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.5 and newer?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/kd1sQW

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "quotation marks and curly brackets are not always consecutive"?

Answer (score 1):

First replace all `{` characters with `{\n`. You will also be replacing `{"` with `{\n"`. Now, you can replace back all `{\n"` characters with `{"`.

```
text = 'hello(){imagine{puts("{HELLO}")}}'
replaced = text.replace('{', '{\n').replace('{\n"','{"')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may match single and double quoted (C-style) string literals (those that support escape entities with backslashes) and then match `{` and `}` in any other context that you may replace with your desired values.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kd1sQW):

```
import re
text = 'hello(){imagine{puts("{HELLO}")}}'
dblq = r'(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"'
snlq = r"(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'"
rx = re.compile(r'({}|{})|[{{}}]'.format(dblq, snlq))
print(rx.pattern)
def repl(m):
    if m.group(1):
        return m.group(1)
    elif m.group() == '{':
        return '{\n'
    else:
        return '\n}'

# Examples
print(rx.sub(repl, text))
print(rx.sub(repl, r'hello(){imagine{puts("Nice, Mr. \"Know-all\"")}}'))
print(rx.sub(repl, "hello(){imagine{puts('MORE {HELLO} HERE ')}}"))
```

The pattern that is generated in the code above is

```
((?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')|[{}]
```

It can actually be reduced to

```
(?<!\\)((?:\\{2})*(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'))|[{}]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PXGz9u/2).

**Details**:

The pattern matches 2 main alternatives. The first one matches single- and double-quoted string literals.

- `(?<!\\)` - no `\` immediately to the left is allowed
- `((?:\\{2})*(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'))` - Group 1:

  - `(?:\\{2})*` - 0+ repetitions of two consecutive backslashes
  - `(?:` - a non-capturing group:

    - `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`  - a double quoted string literal
    - `|`  - or
    - `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'` - a single quoted string literal
  - `)` - end of the  non-capturing group
- `|` - or

  - `[{}]` - a `{` or `}`.

In the `repl` method, Group 1 is checked for a match. If it matched, the single- or double-quoted string literal is matched, it must be put back where it was. Else, if the match value is `{`, it is replaced with `{\n`, else, with `\n}`.

Comment: I appreciate it. your explanation is very helpful for me. also, the regex101 is a very good site!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the similarities with the input and try to match them.

```
text = 'hello(){imagine{puts("{HELLO}")}}'
replaced = text.replace('){', '){\n').replace('{puts', '{\nputs').replace('}}', '\n}\n}')
print(replaced)
```

output:

```
hello(){
imagine{
puts("{HELLO}")
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

try this: https://regex101.com/r/DBgkrb/1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but the text can be changed. it can also be `imagine{"{dragons}"}`

Comment: the function 'imagine' can change as well?

Comment: Yes, it is. probably everything can be changed.

Comment: Ok, so what similarities between the input data? The objective for this is to ident the code breaking the lines with "{","}" but taking careful because you might have some brackets inside double quotes ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{` with `{\n`:

```
text.replace('{', '{\n')
```

Replace `}` with `\n}`:

```
text.replace('}', '\n}')
```

Now to fix the braces that were quoted:

```
text.replace('"{\n','"{')
```

and

```
text.replace('\n}"', '}"')
```

Combined together:

```
replaced = text.replace('{', '{\n').replace('}', '\n}').replace('"{\n','"{').replace('\n}"', '}"')
```

**Output**

```
hello(){
imagine{
puts("{HELLO}")
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, quotation marks and curly brackets are not always consecutive.

Comment: If you are sure the answer does not work, please update your question to further outline the restrictions! :)

Comment: I'm sorry for being late. this solution is replacing "H{E" to "H{\nE". but it doesn't need to replace.